# Fetch data realtime from Firestore with where condition

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function which fetches data from Firestore using `where` and `get`. The problem is if a new record is added, it is not pushed to client side realtime. I know that I have to use `.valueChanges()` but I also need to fetch data with `.where()` condition because I can't fetch the entire data

I only need to fetch data of the `logged in user`. That is why `where` condition is needed.

How do I use both together ?

This is my current code:

```
assign_by(){
  this.goalList =[];
  this.storage.get('loggedInUser').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your user ID is', val);
    this.loggedInusr = val;

    firebase.firestore().collection(`todos`)
    //.where("assignTo", "==", this.loggedInusr)
   .where("assignBy", "==", this.loggedInusr)
   //.where("followers", "array-contains", this.loggedInusr)
    .get()
   //.valueChanges()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log("assignby");
            console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
            this.goalList.push(doc.data());
        });
      });

  });
}
```

### Edit 1

As guided, I have changed my current code like below:

```
assign_to(){

      this.goalList =[];
      this.storage.get('loggedInUser').then((val) => {
        console.log('Your user ID is', val);
        this.loggedInusr = val;
        firebase.firestore().collection(`todos`)
        .where("assignTo", "==", this.loggedInusr)
       .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {           
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.data());
            console.log("assignby");
            console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
            this.goalList.push(doc.data());
        });
    });
      });
    }
```

New record is added by logged in user, so new record should be seen on this screen which shows all records assigned by this user.

I added this record:

[image]

But it is not updated here:

[image]

### Edit 2

Showing `assign_by()` function as above screenshot comes from this function. Note that if I open this page again, new records can be seen.

```
assign_by(){
  this.goalList =[];
  this.storage.get('loggedInUser').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your user ID is', val);
    this.loggedInusr = val;

    firebase.firestore().collection(`todos`)
    //.where("assignTo", "==", this.loggedInusr)
   .where("assignBy", "==", this.loggedInusr)

    // .get()
    // .then(querySnapshot => {
      .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {           
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.data());
            console.log("assignby");
            console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
            this.goalList.push(doc.data());
        });
    });

        // querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
        //     // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        //     console.log("assignby");
        //     console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
        //     this.goalList.push(doc.data());
        // });
      // });

  });
}
```

Comment: Reminder: the personal pronoun is a capital letter "I", with no exceptions. If you're struggling to remember this, install an English spellchecker into your browser, and ensure you use it before publishing.

Comment: the personal pronoun is a capital letter "I" .... I have noted this :)

Comment: Reminder: the personal pronoun is a capital letter "I", with no exceptions. If you're struggling to remember this, install an English spellchecker into your browser, and ensure you use it before publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very well call the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#on-snapshot) method on a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query), as follows:

```
    firebase.firestore().collection('todos')
   .where("assignBy", "==", this.loggedInusr)
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {           
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.data());
        });
    });
```

---

By doing `firebase.firestore().collection('todos').where("assignBy", "==", this.loggedInusr).get()` you are actually querying the database **only once**, therefore you cannot detect if there were any changed (e.g. records added) in the collection (that corresponds to your query) after this initial and **unique** fetch. See the `get()` method doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get).

Comment: i have done as you guided, i have updated the question under `Edit:: 1` , but still it did not updated, am i still doing something wrong ?

Comment: It seems from the screenshots added to your question that `this.loggedInusr` (i.e. `Ddy1...`) corresponds to `assignBy` not `assignTo`, but your query is `.where("assignTo", "==", this.loggedInusr)`

Comment: screenshot is of `My assigned works`, it uses function `assign_by` , i have updated the question with this function too, you can see `Edit::2`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comments and update. Are you still having a problem? If yes, please explain it very precisely by sharing the exact elements.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. There is no "onSnapshot" function exist. FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('userId', isEqualTo: loggedInUserId)
      .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.data());
        });
    });